# How can I scale a point so that it can fit every device's screen in Android

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a skeleton image and mark some keypoints on it. If I use fixed points in a specific device, points move another place for different device's screen. I know it is the problem for device resolution and I should scale the point. But How to do that? I use canvas in jetpack for drawing those keypoints. Please help me so that the point show exact position for different device's screen. Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun ShowModalSkeleton(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val color = remember { mutableStateOf(Color(0xFF1176B4)) }
    var zoomLevel by remember { mutableStateOf(1.0f) }
    var panOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset(0f,0f)) }


    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(vertical = 12.dp)
                .transformable(
                    state = rememberTransformableState { zoomDelta, offsetDelta, _ ->
                        zoomLevel *= zoomDelta
                        panOffset += offsetDelta
                    }
                )
        ) {
            ImageWithPoint(
                zoomLevel = zoomLevel,
                panOffset = panOffset
            )
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .graphicsLayer(
                        scaleX = zoomLevel,
                        scaleY = zoomLevel,
                        translationX = panOffset.x,
                        translationY = panOffset.y
                    )
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures { offset ->
                            
                        }
                    }

            ) {
                // Draw your canvas content here
                val keyPoints: List<Offset> = listOf(
                    Offset(333.dp.toPx(), 70.dp.toPx())
                )
                Log.d("Converted","${30.dp.toPx()}")

                for (keypoint in keyPoints) {
                    drawCircle(
                        color = color.value,
                        radius = 15f,
                        center = keypoint
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun ImageWithPoint(
    zoomLevel: Float,
    panOffset: Offset
) {
    val imagePainter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.front_image)
    Image(
        painter = imagePainter,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = zoomLevel,
                scaleY = zoomLevel,
                translationX = panOffset.x,
                translationY = panOffset.y
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: Why do you draw at fixed dp points instead of percentage of width and height of canvas? You can draw at size.width*.3f, size.height*.4f for instance. It would be at drawn at same percentage above and left side of the canvas on every device.